# Powershell: use values from json as parameter defaults

Tags: json, powershell, parameters

I want to write a script with parameters, where the default values for those parameters are stored in a json file. Unfortunately, Powershell does not recognise `param()` if it is not the first line of code within the script.

But of course if it is the first line of the script, it cannot load the config in advance  and use its value as default value. So I am in anpickle.

The `config.json`:

```
{"defaultValue":"Default"}
```

The powershell script:

```
$configPath = "config.json"
$configPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $configPath

# read config
$config = Get-Content $configPath | ConvertFrom-Json

write-host $config.defaultValue

param($myparam = $config.defaultValue)

write-host $myparam
```

I am new to powershell, is there a way to set default values of parameters later in the script? Or alternatively, read parameters later into the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter default values can be assigned via arbitrary commands, and as long as your default values are parameter-specific and do not rely on the values of other parameters (or variables defined later in the script), the use of self-contained commands to determine default values is a viable option:

```sh
param(
  $myparam = (ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content -Raw $PSScriptRoot/config.json)).defaultValue
)

# Output the parameter value for diagnostic purposes.
"[$myparam]"
```

The only potential problem is that if you want to assign *multiple* parameters' default values this way, you'll have to *duplicate* (variations of) this command:

- Performance-wise, I suspect this won't be a problem, though (unless the JSON is file is large and there are many parameters).
- If you dislike the duplication aspect for maintenance reasons, use an after-the-fact approach based on the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters), as shown in [Manual Batsching's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68036769/45375).

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume your `config.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "Name": "Earthling",
    "Color": "Pink"
}
```

Depending on your actual scenario you could pass the path to the `config.json` in as a parameter and make all the other parameters optional.

Within the script you load the config and provide default values for all parameters that have not been set in the script invocation:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $Name,

    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $Color,

    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $ConfigPath
)

    if ($ConfigPath -in  $PSBoundParameters.Keys) {

        $config = Get-Content $ConfigPath | ConvertFrom-Json

        if ('Name' -notin  $PSBoundParameters.Keys) {
            $Name = $config.Name
        } 
        if ('Color' -notin  $PSBoundParameters.Keys) {
            $Color = $config.Color
        } 
    }

    Write-Host "$Name your favourite color is $Color"
```

You would call the script like this:

```
PS> ./script.ps1  -ConfigPath ./config.json -Color Blue

Earthling your favourite color is Blue
```

That has the downside, that you cannot declare parameters as mandatory. An alternative approach that allows declaring parameters as mandatory would be to pipe the configuration into your script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,Mandatory)]
    [string]
    $Name,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,Mandatory)]
    [string]
    $Color
)

    Write-Host "$Name your favourite color is $Color"
```

The invocation would then be:

```
PS> Get-Content ./params.json | ConvertFrom-Json | ./script.ps1 -Color Red

Earthling your favourite color is Red
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `DynamicParam  { }` block and possibly the `Set-Variable` cmdlet for this.
The disadvantage is that you can't set the related variable (like `$Name`) but could use `$PSBoundParameters[$Name]` instead or assign the bare variable names within the `Begin` block.
Quick and dirty example (no check e.g. if the related parameter really exist):

```
Function Test {
    [CmdletBinding()] param (
        [Parameter()][string]$Name,
        [Parameter()][string]$Color
    )
    DynamicParam {
        $Defaults = ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable '{
            "Name": "Earthling",
            "Color": "Pink"
        }'
        ForEach ($Key in $Defaults.get_Keys()) { 
            if (!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($Key)) { $PSBoundParameters[$Key] = $Defaults[$Key] }
        }
    }
    Begin {
        ForEach ($Key in $PSBoundParameters.get_Keys()) { Set-Variable $Key $PSBoundParameters[$Key] }
    }
    Process {
        Write-Host 'Name:' $Name
        Write-Host 'Color:' $Color
    }
}
```

```
Test -Name Jim
Name: Jim
Color: Pink
```

Comment: The check if the parameters were set is needed though, otherwise `Test -Name Jim -Color Blue` will still return the default-values "Earthling" and "Pink"..

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [PSDefaultParameterValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.1); so you could load the JSON file into this hashtable at the start of your script.

To get around `param` needing to be at the start of the script, and to give you a function name to use in the `PSDefaultParameterValues` hashtable, you can define the core logic of your script in a function definition inside the script. Then the script itself just does 3 things:

- read the JSON file and sets PSDefaultParameterValues
- defines the function
- invokes the function

I think this approach is simpler than DynamicParams and encourages the good practive of encapsulating your code into re-usable functions, and scripts are really just wrappers that invoke said functions.